# Working Time Calculator c++

Tags: time, calculator

Can someone help me? I am creating a program where the user have to input time in and time out per day to compute weekly working hour. The program is directed to accept military time (e.g. 800, 1700, 2030, etc.). There is no error in my code but I have a problem in conversion. If i input 845 for time in and 1600 for time out. The program must display 7.15. Meaning 7 hours and 15 minutes made for that day. But (1600 - 845) / 100 will not work because the answer is 7.55

Here is the program

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
int day;
double mHr, tHr, wHr, thHr, fHr;
double in, out, total1;
char holiday;
do
{
    switch(day)
    {
    case 0:
        cout<<"Time In for Monday: ";
        cin>>in;
        cout<<"Enter Time Out for Monday: ";
        cin>>out;
        if (in<=800)
        {
            in = 800;
        }
        if (out>=1700)
        {
            out = 1700;
        }
        if ((out-in)<=400)
        {
            mHr = out - in;
        }
        else if ((out-in)>=500)
        {
            mHr = (out - in) - 100;
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        cout<<"Enter Time In for Tuesday: ";
        cin>>in;
        cout<<"Enter Time Out for Tuesday: ";
        cin>>out;
        if (in<=800)
        {
            in = 800;
        }
        if (out>=1700)
        {
            out = 1700;
        }
        if ((out-in)<=400)
        {
            tHr = out - in;
        }
        else if ((out-in)>=500)
        {
            tHr = (out - in) - 100;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        cout<<"Enter Time In for Wednesday: ";
        cin>>in;
        cout<<"Enter Time Out for Wednesday: ";
        cin>>out;
        if (in<=800)
        {
            in = 800;
        }
        if (out>=1700)
        {
            out = 1700;
        }
        if ((out-in)<=400)
        {
            wHr = out - in;
        }
        else if ((out-in)>=500)
        {
            wHr = (out - in) - 100;
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        cout<<"Enter Time In for Thursday: ";
        cin>>in;
        cout<<"Enter Time Out for Thursday: ";
        cin>>out;
        if (in<=800)
        {
            in = 800;
        }
        if (out>=1700)
        {
            out = 1700;
        }
        if ((out-in)<=400)
        {
            thHr = out - in;
        }
        else if ((out-in)>=500)
        {
            thHr = (out - in) - 100;
        }
        break;

    case 4:
        cout<<"Enter Time In for Friday: ";
        cin>>in;
        cout<<"Enter Time Out for Friday: ";
        cin>>out;
        if (in<=800)
        {
            in = 800;
        }
        if (out>=1700)
        {
            out = 1700;
        }
        if ((out-in)<=400)
        {
            fHr = out - in;
        }
        else if ((out-in)>=500)
        {
            fHr = (out - in) - 100;
        }
        break;

    }
    day = day + 1;
}
while(day<5);
total1 = (mHr + tHr + wHr + thHr + fHr) / 100;
cout<<"*********************************************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"Weekly Time Record:"<<endl;
cout<<" The total number of working hours for regular hours: "<<total1<<" Hrs."<<endl;
cout<<"*********************************************************************"<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: So `16:00 - 08:45 == (16+0/60)-(8+45/60) == (16-8)+(0-45)/60 == 8-15/60 == 7:45`.  You have to treat the rightmost two digits as sexagesimal fractions, not decimal fractions.

Comment: thanks. but the answer should be 7 hours and 15 minutes. not 7 hours and 45 mins. 8:45 am to 1600(4:00 pm) will be 7 hours and 15 minutes of work

Comment: So do the calculations correctly, I obviously didn't !

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is probably to convert each input time to the number of minutes elapsed since midnight, and then subtract the two:

```
double calculateHours(int militaryStartTime, int militaryEndTime)
{
    int startHours = militaryStartTime / 100;
    int startMinutes = militaryStartTime % 100;
    int startTime = startHours * 60 + startMinutes; // minutes since midnight

    int endHours = militaryEndTime / 100;
    int endMinutes = militaryEndTime % 100;
    int endTime = endHours * 60 + endMinutes; // minutes since midnight

    return (endTime - startTime) / 60.0;
}
```